# uimanageddocument not saving (coreData)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm following the standford online ios course to test the basics of core data, and I'm running into difficulty simply saving data.  Right now, I have the code block below, which outputs "file does not exist"...meaning that it never enters the block where I create the context and save the data.  Why is it saying that the document does not exist? Please help, I'm a noobie.

```
  NSString * text = self.userTextField.text;
//save this text
NSLog(@"entered button function");
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL* docDir = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
NSString *documentName = @"myDoc";
NSURL* url = [docDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
UIManagedDocument *doc = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]];
if (fileExists)
{
    [doc openWithCompletionHandler: ^(BOOL success) {
        if (doc.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal){
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = doc.managedObjectContext;
            TallyEntry* entry1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TallyEntry" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            entry1.name = text;
            NSLog(@"entry1 saved");
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"not ready");

    }];
       }
else
    NSLog(@"file does not exist");
```

I also tried removing the whole Bool fileExists part and just running:

```
if (doc.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal){
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = doc.managedObjectContext;
            TallyEntry* entry1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TallyEntry" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            entry1.name = text;
            NSLog(@"entry1 saved");
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"not ready");

    }];
```

But this doesn't work, and it keeps outputting "not ready"...which means the doc is not in a normal state.  How do I change this?

Comment: You never really saved the UIManagedDocument.  You just used its managed object context to save the TallyEntry object

Comment: But shouldn't bool fileExists return true because I literally initialized the document at that URL right above it?

Comment: Unless you call saveToURL:forSaveOperation:completionHandler: the file will not exist. You have only initialized the document at that URL not save it.   https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocument_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDocument/initWithFileURL:

Comment: Where would I put that save? immediately after I initialize it?

Comment: It is up to you, you could save if the file does not exist at the URL otherwise you can open the file as the document states